# Air Cooler and Health Issues

Tags: allergy, common-cold, air-quality

I am new to air cooling appliances at home.
Now, I am planing to buy a air **cooler** ( **not** conditioner), but I **heard** that it will create health issues such as **dust allergy, cold** etc.

Because It contains **Coir**.
Once this coir is **old** & wet, then it will pollute the air and this leads to cold,dust allergy etc.

Anyone have any bad experiences like this? Please share..